# HttpClient 4.1.x error for self signed certificate (javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated )

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to configure the Tomcat6 with self-signed certificates with clientAuth=true & then to call the Tomcat server on client side using HttpClient 4.1.x.

I followed the instruction provided in the http://virgo47.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/tomcat-web-application-with-ssl-client-certificates/ & it is working fine as expected when I am testing from the browser or from the openssl client (I ran the command "openssl s_client -cert client.crt -key client.key -CAfile ca.crt -connect localhost:8443").

The problem I am facing is with the HttpClient. I wrote the following code to create HttpClient

```
    private DefaultHttpClient creatHttpClient(KeyStore keyStore, 
        char[] keyStorePassword, KeyStore trustStore, char[] trustStorePassword) {
    try {

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
                TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore); // This contains CA certs
        TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword); // This contain client private key
        KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(km, tm, new SecureRandom());

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, 
                SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);

        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 
                443, sslSocketFactory));

        ClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = 
                new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(schemeRegistry);

        final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                clientConnectionManager, params);
        return httpClient;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

For this, I received

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
```

I enabled the debug

```
    static
    { System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake,trustmanager"); }
```

I received the following debug logs

```
    main, handling exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error:                      java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error 
    main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
    main, called closeSocket()
    main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
    main, called close()
    main, called closeInternal(true)
    main, called close()
    main, called closeInternal(true)
```

What could be possibly going wrong in this case? I don't want to ignore the ssl certificates error rather want to authenticate properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. The issue was that I was loading keystore & trust store using

```
InputStream ksin = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("client.jks");
InputStream tsin = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("cacerts.jks");
```

& was using these lines in the Junit tests & it was not able to find .jks files.

I figured out this by putting the following

```
if(0 == keyStore.size()) { throw new RuntimeException("Keystore is empty"); }
if(0 == trustStore.size()) { throw new RuntimeException("Truststore is empty"); }
```

after keystore & truststore initialization.

So, I changed the lines to

```
InputStream ksin = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("client.jks");
InputStream tsin = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cacerts.jks");
```

& everything worked fine.