# With https URL, HttpsURLConnection works but HttpClient does not

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpsurlconnection

I have a web app (on WebSphere) that interacts with 3rd party to format some received data, and then make RESTful call to said 3rd party, which resides on a `Tomcat server`.  Within the web app I can successfully make a basic RESTful `GET` call using Java's native `HttpsUrlConnection` (see below), but when I use Apache's `HttpClient`, it fails with an `SSL` chaining error.

The HttpsURLConnection:

```
    String urlWithParams = "https://example.com/rest/issue/59"; 

    String methodType = "GET"; 
    String acceptType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;

    HttpsURLConnection conn = null; 

    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlWithParams);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod(methodType);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", acceptType);

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Failed. httpErrorUrl=" + conn.getResponseCode()
                    + " httpErrorCode=" + conn.getResponseCode()
                    + " httpErrorMsg=" + conn.getResponseMessage());

        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

        String rawData;
        String toReturn = "";
        while ((rawData = br.readLine()) != null) {
            toReturn += rawData;
        }

        System.out.println(toReturn);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(conn != null){
            conn.disconnect();
        } else {
            System.out.println("httpUrlConnection is null");
        }
    }
```

The HttpClient code:

```
    String uri = "https://example.com/rest/issue/59"; 
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    connManager.setMaxTotal(40);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

The HttpClient methods are executed in the function below:

```
    private JSON request(HttpRequestBase req) throws RestException, IOException {
        req.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        if (creds != null)
            creds.authenticate(req);

        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(req);
        HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        if (ent != null) {
            String encoding = null;
            if (ent.getContentEncoding() != null) {
                encoding = ent.getContentEncoding().getValue();
            }

            if (encoding == null) {
                Header contentTypeHeader = resp.getFirstHeader("Content-Type");
                HeaderElement[] contentTypeElements = contentTypeHeader.getElements();
                for (HeaderElement he : contentTypeElements) {
                    NameValuePair nvp = he.getParameterByName("charset");
                    if (nvp != null) {
                        encoding = nvp.getValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            InputStreamReader isr =  encoding != null ?
                new InputStreamReader(ent.getContent(), encoding) :
                new InputStreamReader(ent.getContent());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                result.append(line);
        }

        StatusLine sl = resp.getStatusLine();

        if (sl.getStatusCode() >= 300)
            throw new RestException(sl.getReasonPhrase(), sl.getStatusCode(), result.toString());

        return result.length() > 0 ? JSONSerializer.toJSON(result.toString()): null;
    }
```

The error produced is a typical chaining exception, which usually means the `SSL` certs are not correct.  Since the certs are imported at the App Server level, I would expect the `SSL` connections to be handled the same for both `HttpsURLConnection` and `HttpClient` calls.

```
Caused by: `com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: PKIX` path building failed: `java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl` co
```

uld not build a valid `CertPath.;` internal cause is:
        `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:` The certificate issued by CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority, OU="(c) 2
006 Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/CPS is incorporated by reference, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is:

```
    `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:` Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:18) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:118) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:14) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.a(pc.java:41) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.checkServerTrusted(pc.java:1) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.b(pc.java:90) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:499) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: `java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:` PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.
        at `com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:411)` ~[na:na]
        at `java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:258)` ~[na:na]
        at `com.ibm.jsse2.util.h.b(h.java:61) ~[na:6.0 build_20141024]
        ... 86` common frames omitted

Why are certificates being applied for `HttpsURLConnection` but not for `HttpClient`?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess this is an issue with SNI, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879894/android-ssl-sni-support. If if this post is form 2011 it is still relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient does not take system properties into account unless explicitly configured to do do.

Try replacing

```
HttpClients.createDefault()
```

with

```
HttpClients.createSystem()
```

Please also note that `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` instance in your code is not used. Do not create custom connection managers unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks @oleg. Wow, I cannot believe after all of my google searching on Apache HttpClient and SSL I did not come across HttpClients.createSystem().  Thank you very much for the info, it fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

The following question has a good code example on how to use HTTPS over HttpClient.

[Using Apache httpclient for https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206010/using-apache-httpclient-for-https)

In brief: your code is missing all of the HTTP**S** specific setup.. you are using it as if it was just a regular HTTP request.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying.  In the [HttpClient SSL Docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html), it states that **Once you have JSSE correctly installed, secure HTTP communication over SSL should be as simple as plain HTTP communication**.  Since the source of my call is within WebSphere, it should handle all of the SSL negotiations (like it does when I use HttpsURLConnection, right?

Comment: Does not seem like that is the case now does it. Try the example given in the linked post and see if it works.